# Active Directory Search getting Object reference not set

Tags: c#, active-directory

The below code works on my local machine by returning the user's full name from Active Directory:

```
string principal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Remove(0, 12);

string filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", principal);

string[] properties = new string[] { "fullname" };

DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myserver.com");
adRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);

searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;

searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);

searcher.Filter = filter;

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName) == false)
{
    return displayName;
}
```

When I publish it to the development server I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

The error is thrown on the following line:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

I have tried

```
DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, AdAdminUsername, AdAdminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

but still no joy.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from outside : your string called `principal` is built by the following :

```
string principal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Remove(0, 12);
```

Have you log `'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`' on your dev server ? This static construction may be the begining of you troubles because if `principal` is'nt what you think it is, the result of FindOne may be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code, you **must** check for `NULL` after the call to `FindOne()` - it could return a `NULL` value if no matching directory entry was found.

[See the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone.aspx):

> If more than one entry is found during the search, only the first
>   entry is returned. *If no entries are found to match the search
>   criteria, **a null reference** (Nothing in Visual Basic) is returned.*

Plus, you should also **always check** for the presence of a property before accessing it - it could be absent.....

Therefore, your code should be something like this:

```
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

if(result != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

    if(directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"] != null &&
       directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"].Length > 0)
    {
       string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
       {
          return displayName;
       }
    }
}
```

---

But: if you're on .NET 3.5 or newer, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which makes a lot of things a lot easier when dealing with Active Directory.

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.SamAccountName = "whatever you're looking for.....";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `Surname` (or last name)
- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply.  Again, this works locally, but on the development server, with the same user, the search is not finding anything.

Comment: @user390480: then you probably have to create a specific user for AD access, and define that when you search - in .NET 3.5, when you create the `PrincipalContext`

Comment: I have a specific user for AD access.  You can see where I tried it in my above code under "I have tried".  Maybe I am not implementing it correctly.